# Unable to install Wordpress on Amazon's EC2 instance due to missing php-mbstring

Tags: amazon-ec2, php, rhel7

I've created a new instance on Amazon's EC2 and I'm trying in `wordpress` and it's failing due to `php-mbstring`:

```
# yum install wordpress
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package wordpress.noarch 0:3.9.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-simplepie >= 1.3.1 for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-gd for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-enchant for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-PHPMailer for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-PHPMailer.noarch 0:5.2.6-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.1.0 for package: php-PHPMailer-5.2.6-1.el7.noarch
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-simplepie.noarch 0:1.3.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-simplepie-1.3.1-4.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-IDNA_Convert for package: php-simplepie-1.3.1-4.el7.noarch
---> Package wordpress.noarch 0:3.9.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-enchant for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.0-2.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-common = 1.6.0-2.1.el7 for package: libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-5.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libpng.x86_64 2:1.5.13-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-IDNA_Convert.noarch 0:0.8.0-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-IDNA_Convert-0.8.0-2.el7.noarch
---> Package php-PHPMailer.noarch 0:5.2.6-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.1.0 for package: php-PHPMailer-5.2.6-1.el7.noarch
---> Package php-simplepie.noarch 0:1.3.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-simplepie-1.3.1-4.el7.noarch
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-14.el7 will be installed
---> Package wordpress.noarch 0:3.9.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-enchant for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.0-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.9-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.9-5.el7.x86_64
---> Package php-IDNA_Convert.noarch 0:0.8.0-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-IDNA_Convert-0.8.0-2.el7.noarch
---> Package php-PHPMailer.noarch 0:5.2.6-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.1.0 for package: php-PHPMailer-5.2.6-1.el7.noarch
---> Package php-simplepie.noarch 0:1.3.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-simplepie-1.3.1-4.el7.noarch
---> Package wordpress.noarch 0:3.9.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-enchant for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-IDNA_Convert.noarch 0:0.8.0-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-IDNA_Convert-0.8.0-2.el7.noarch
---> Package php-PHPMailer.noarch 0:5.2.6-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.1.0 for package: php-PHPMailer-5.2.6-1.el7.noarch
---> Package php-simplepie.noarch 0:1.3.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-simplepie-1.3.1-4.el7.noarch
---> Package wordpress.noarch 0:3.9.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-enchant for package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-PHPMailer-5.2.6-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring >= 5.1.0
Error: Package: php-IDNA_Convert-0.8.0-2.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: php-simplepie-1.3.1-4.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: wordpress-3.9.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-enchant
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
#
```

I'm using RHEL7:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
repo id                                                                                                     repo name                                                                                                                   status
epel/x86_64                                                                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                              4,325
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64                                                                   Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 7                                                                 1
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64                                                             Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (RPMs)                                                                                    4,447
repolist: 8,773
#
```

a while back and another environment I had to run following command first in order to get access to `php-mbstring`:

`rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6`

How do you do that in Amazon EC2?:

Comment: What does this have to do with Amazon EC2? It looks like your question is about RHEL 7.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I guess it's bit different on EC2 in terms of how subscription is handled.

Comment: Nothing to do with EC2. These packages don't appear to be in RHEL 7 at all. They aren't in the manifest, which makes me wonder how on earth they managed to package wordpress succesfully.

Comment: in `rhel6` it's under `optional`, i'd assume it's same in rhel7 but i may be wrong..

Comment: I'd advise against installing WordPress as a package.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok, regardless to that, I still need `php-mbstring` and I'd like to have it as a package.

Comment: I suggest you do what everyone else does and add the `remi` repo.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, that didn't answer my question exactly, however it did the job) so, if you want to post that as answer I'll accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the [package manifest](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Package_Manifest/index.html), the build of PHP included with RHEL 7 is pretty minimal, and a lot of extensions are missing. They don't seem to be in any other channel, either.

Many people use [the remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) for up-to-date and complete builds of PHP, and you may wish to do this as well. Repos are currently available for PHP 5.4 and 5.5.

Comment: Just a note that PHP from remi repository will likely to be conflicting with RHEL PHP. So choose one and dont mix them.

Answer (score 1):

php-mbstrings is available in RHEL7 via rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7 channel.

```
rhn-channel -c rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7 -a; yum info php-mbstrings

yum info php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                    | 4.3 kB  00:00:00
Installed Packages
Name        : php-mbstring
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.4.16
Release     : 21.el7
Size        : 1.3 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7
Summary     : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP and LGPLv2 and BSD and OpenLDAP
Description : The php-mbstring package contains a dynamic shared object that will add
            : support for multi-byte string handling to PHP.
```

Comment: The optional channel (nor any other channel) is not available to Amazon EC2 RHEL users, as far as I know. I would like to know if this is wrong and there is some way to get it.

Comment: This is for Amazon to sort out with Redhat. Amazon use RHUI and they need to subscribe to the channel. See :  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=551601